# WMDropFiles problem on win7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, drag-and-drop, windows-vista, delphi-2010

I've implemented the following procedure and it works properly when I compile it on my computer running windows vista, computer #1. If I share the created .exe file to another computer running win7, computer #2, it runs fine aswell. The problem is when I let the computer #2 compile it, it wont simply recognize that anything's dropped on the application. There's no response at all in this code. It's built and compiled without errors or warnings. 
I've been searching the net for a while without finding anything that explains why this happens or someone else with this problem.

Both computers use Delphi 2010 with the same components installed.

1. Is this the way to go to allow the user to drop files onto the application? If not, how should it be done nowdays?
2. Any ideas why it works when it's compiled on computer #1 but not computer #2? (The program works properly on both computers when compiled on computer #1)

Any help or comment is highly appreciated.

```
procedure TfMainForm.WMDROPFILES(var msg: TWMDropFiles);
const
  MaxLength = 255;

var
  nFiles : integer;
  i : integer;
  fileName : array [0..MaxLength] of char;
  fileNames : TStringArray;

begin
  // Get number of files dropped
  nFiles := DragQueryFile(msg.Drop,  $FFFFFFFF, fileName, MaxLength);

  // Get filenames
  SetLength(fileNames, nFiles);
  for i := 0 to nFiles - 1 do begin
    DragQueryFile(msg.Drop, i, fileName, MaxLength);
    fileNames[i] := fileName;
  end;

    // Add files
  projectHandler.addFiles(fileNames);

  //release memory
  DragFinish(msg.Drop);
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess that if you are running from within the IDE on computer #2. I bet that if you compile on computer #2 but start the executable from explorer rather than from the IDE, it works. The final piece of the jigsaw is that I bet you are running your IDE on computer #2 as administrator.

On Vista and Windows 7 you can't send messages to a process with a higher integrity level. If your process is being run as administrator then it will have a higher integrity level than explorer and so won't accept the dropped files.

If my guess is correct I recommend that you stop running Delphi as administrator, it doesn't need this.

As for whether or not `WM_DROPFILES` is a reasonable approach, I see no problems with using it.

Comment: I'm actually running computer #1 (vista) as administrator, don't know about computer #2 though. I will try running the executable from the explorer next time I get my hands on the computer. What's the difference from running the executable versus from IDE?

Comment: If you run elevated then low integrity processes can't send you messages. If your IDE is elevated then your app will be too when you run from IDE.

Comment: You can use [ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388202(v=vs.85).aspx) to allow `WM_DROPFILES` to be received from lower privileged processes.

Comment: @TOndrej Well, you can, but that's not really the best approach.

Comment: @David That probably depends on what you're approaching. ;-)

Comment: WM_DROPFILES has been deprecated for years. You really should be using the IDropTarget interface instead. It is much more flexible than WM_DROPFILES without the limitations.DropTarget interface instead. It is much more flexible than WM_DROPFILES without the limitations.

Comment: @remy I use IDropTarget myself, but if WM_DROPFILES works why not use it.

Comment: Like I said, WM_DROPFILES is deprecated. Even Microsoft says to use IDropTarget instead. If you implement IDropTarget, you can accept additional types of drags that WM_DROPFILES cannot handle. If you don't implement it, then a drag of an IDataObject containing HDROP data is automatically converted to a WM_DROPFILES message but only for backwards compatibility. If you handle the IDataObject directly, you get better performance and support for additional sources and formats.

Comment: @Remy Could you please point me to the MS documentation that explains this deprecation of WM_DROPFILES?

Comment: @TOndrej: Using `ChangeWindowMessageFilter/Ex()` is correct to allow `WM_DROPFILES` to work with UIPI, but there are other messages that must also be enabled in order for `WM_DROPFILES` to work correctly.  See http://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-enable-drag-and-drop-for-an-elevated-mfc-application-on-vistawindows-7/

Comment: Running the executable worked. Upgrading the code to use the IDropTarget interface is on the todo-list but since it's only a neat feature for the user and it works for now it's low prio :)

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, not true. While DragXXX and WM_DROPFILES is old but is has never been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

At http://www.web-developer.de/content/download/7387/137496/file/Listings.zip you can find an example written using Delphi XE (compiles with D2010 as well). The subfolder "2_WmDropFiles" contains a project "WmDropFiles.dpr" that shows how to an app that runs elevated can receive files from an app which does not run elevated. The comments etc. are in German, so please use Google translate when in doubt.

Hope this helps,
Olaf

Comment: Don't you mean "how an elevated app can receive files from one that isn't elevated"?

Comment: For me it doesn't work under Win 8 (tried example from Listings.zip). Seems there is no way to drag-drop from app with lower integrity to app with higher integrity with Windows 8 (at least i can't find any solution).